# Why is "isometric" not part of "isomorphism"?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, isometry

Suppose we have two normed/metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ and suppose $X$ and $Y$ are isometrically isomorphic meaning there exists an isomorphism $T: X \rightarrow Y$ which is also an isometry. This is the "nicest" map possible between these spaces.

However, if one should think of an isomorphism in general as something that "preserves structure", why is isometry property not just contained in the definition of an isomorphism? Wouldn't one expect that distances is part of the structure of a set (with a distance function)?

In Rudin's "Functional Analysis", he also writes "isometric isomorphism" when appropriate. So from I can tell this in the general notion? Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Comment: Definition: A function $f : (X, d) → (Y,ρ)$ is an *isomorphism* if $f$ is an isometry and $f$ is surjective. See [here](https://www.math.ncku.edu.tw/~fjmliou/advcal/Completion.pdf), Definition $1.3$.

Comment: There really is not a lot to say. If $X \cong Y$ as metric spaces, we have to require isometric isomorphism. If $X \cong Y$ as topological spaces, we have to require homeomorphism. One is strictly stronger than the other, but both have their uses.

Comment: It's just terminology. If someone was of a category theoretic mindset then "isomorphism" would be sufficient if one made clear exactly what one's objects and morphisms were. If someone was not of such a mindset they might pick more descriptive/colorful terminology such as "isometric isomorphism". One way or another, if the author expresses themself clearly and you understand clearly, then carry on reading.

Comment: You can view the same set as the set of elements for many different structures. For example, we can view the real numbers as an additive group where a homomorphism preserves addition. We can also view the real numbers as an ordered set and require that a homomorphism preserves the ordering. It is not necessary that every possible property we've ever seen for a set of objects must be considered when thinking about the set.

Answer (score 4):

This is, as far as I know, a historical accident. From a category-theoretic perspective it comes out of conflating the category of normed spaces (with maps of norm $\le 1$) with the category of topological vector spaces; it's an isomorphism in the latter category but not the former (and an isomorphism in the former is an isometric isomorphism).

Similarly continuous functions were first defined between metric spaces before being defined between topological spaces, and when we talk about homeomorphisms of metric spaces we are really working with isomorphisms in the category of topological spaces. But metric spaces came first and similarly normed spaces came first.

If you'd like to learn much more about the history here I like Dieudonne's *[History of Functional Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444861483)*.